# PubNub. Presence leave trigger event doesn't fire

Tags: pubnub

I'm testing Pubnub 3.7.1. But I have a problem with the leave event trigger that doesn't fired.

I can only see the join and timeout trigger event. Here is some code that I use:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: 'channel',
    presence: manageUsers,
    message: showMessage
});

function manageUsers(message, event, channel) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

UDATE:

Another thing is when I enter in a channel where there are some people connected, I can't get their presence data. I can only get their presence data from new users.

Here is the example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qlqhb677CZhTeR8Sa52x?p=preview

Comment: after you enter a channel you have to use here_now() to get all of the presence data for everyone currently connected ( https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#here_now )

Comment: Also, recommend getting on latest version of the PubNub JavaScript SDK - v3.7.11 http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.11.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as expected.

When a user join, it triggers a 'join' action, and when the user goes idle, the action becomes 'timeout'.

The 'leave' action occurs when a user *unsubcribe* from the channel.

e.g.

```
byeButton.click(function(){
  pubnub.unsubscribe({
    channel : 'channel_1',
    callback: function(m){
        console.log(m.action); // should print 'leave'
    }
 });
});
```

See more at:
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#unsubscribe